# Asterisk ZapScan()/DAHDIScan() only returns dead air

Tags: asterisk

I'm running Asterisk 1.4.26.2, DAHDI 2.2.0.2, and libpri 1.4.10.2 on Ubuntu with a Digium TE122 PRI card connected to my PRI.

I have an extension setup so that managers can monitor calls:

```
# grep 9900 /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf
exten => 9900,1,DAHDIScan()
exten => 9900,2,Hangup
```

For whatever reason, this no longer works. It's not often used, so I don't even know when it stopped working. But now whenever I dial 9900, I just get dead air. The * key works to terminate the call, so I assume the # key is cycling through channels - but even if there's a few calls going on, I get no audio from this extension.

Calling 9900 yields this log message:

```
Executing [9900@from-sip-internal:1] DAHDIScan("SIP/7007-08479148", "") in new stack
```

But switching channels shows nothing.

Documentation on DAHDIScan() or its predecessor ZapScan() is extremely sparse. How do I track this down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that DAHDIScan() is being deprecated by neglect. I contacted Digium support and was pointed at [ChanSpy()](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+ChanSpy) to fulfill the same niche. My new extension 9900 works like a charm:

```
exten => 9900,1,ChanSpy(SIP)  
exten => 9900,2,Hangup
```